# Swagger doesn't see my controller if I remove [ApiController] attribute, but I don't want use it

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

If I remove `[ApiController]` in ASP.NET Core 3.1 attribute Swagger stops seing my controller, I've added `[Controller]` attribute instead, but it didn't help. I don't want automatic model state that comes with `[ApiController]`. How to make Swagger spot my API controller?

Comment: Can you post your startup code? and how you add Swagger and Mvc middleware

Comment: Have you also removed the routing attributes? e.g. `[Route(..)]` and `[HttpGet(...)]`? Swagger requires attribute-routing, so removing these would explain the issue.